Why do I keep getting error NETSDK1152: Found multiple publish output files with the same relative path?
I have a Blazor Server .NET 7 solution with the main entry project called Web.csproj. There are other projects such as Api, WebApi, WebConstants etc... When I build this blazor server project in Visual Studio, all works fine, but when I run the following msbuild command:
msbuild .\Web\Web\Web.csproj /p:SolutionDir=c:\Users\me\Documents\Repos\solution\ /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile

I get the following error:
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.ConflictResolution.targets(112,5): error NETSDK1152: Found multiple publish output files with the same relative path: 
  C:\Users\me\Documents\Repos\solution\Web\Alarming\bin\Debug\net7.0\Api.dll.config, 
  C:\Users\me\Documents\Repos\solution\Web\WebComponents\bin\Debug\net7.0\Api.dll.config, 
  C:\Users\me\Documents\Repos\solution\Web\ElementSelectorWindow\bin\Debug\net7.0\Api.dll.config, 
  C:\Users\me\Documents\Repos\solution\Web\Faceplate\bin\Debug\net7.0\Api.dll.config, 
  C:\Users\me\Documents\Repos\solution\Web\Logs\bin\Debug\net7.0\Api.dll.config, 
  C:\Users\me\Documents\Repos\solution\Web\Summary\bin\Debug\net7.0\Api.dll.config, 
  C:\Users\me\Documents\Repos\solution\Web\Tracking\bin\Debug\net7.0\Api.dll.config, 
C:\Users\me\Documents\Repos\solution\Web\WebComponents\bin\Debug\net7.0\WebComponents.staticwebassets.runtime.json, C:\Users\me\Documents\Repos\solution\Web\ElementSelectorWindow\bin\Debug\net7.0\WebComponents.staticwebassets.runtime.json, C:\Users\me\Documents\Repos\solution\Web\Faceplate\bin\Debug\net7.0\WebComponents.staticwebassets.runtime.json, 
C:\Users\me\Documents\Repos\solution\Web\Logs\bin\Debug\net7.0\WebComponents.staticwebassets.runtime.json, C:\Users\me\Documents\Repos\solution\Web\Summary\bin\Debug\net7.0\WebComponents.staticwebassets.runtime.json, C:\Users\me\Documents\Repos\solution\Web\WebComponents\bin\Release\net7.0\WebComponents.staticwebassets.runtime.json, 
C:\Users\me\Documents\Repos\solution\Web\ElementSelectorWindow\bin\Release\net7.0\WebComponents.staticwebassets.runtime.json, C:\Users\me\Documents\Repos\solution\Web\Faceplate\bin\Release\net7.0\WebComponents.staticwebassets.runtime.json, C:\Users\me\Documents\Repos\solution\Web\Logs\bin\Release\net7.0\WebComponents.staticwebassets.runtime.json, 
C:\Users\me\Documents\Repos\solution\Web\Summary\bin\Release\net7.0\WebComponents.staticwebassets.runtime.json, 

I solved these errors by following advice from here and included the following in each of my csproj files:
<PropertyGroup>
   <ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>false</ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>
</PropertyGroup>

but I think this is just putting a bandate on the real problem. What are these dll.config and staticwebassets.runtime.json files that are produced each time a project is referenced by another and how can I solve this error properly?
Perhaps I should mention, Api is a project referenced by numerous others such as Alarming, WebComponents, ElementSelectorWindow, etc...

I should perhaps mention, all my projects have one and the same build output path, so ProjectA and Project B both reference my Api project and both their output directories are one and the same - which seems not to pose any problems for VS

For example, the Api.dll.config file or Api project, we should ensure that it is only generated and referenced by one project. Multiple projects referencing the same file/project can cause such problems.

Jason, but that would mean that two projects shouldn't reference a common project, in my case my Api project.  It is standard procedure to reference a common project in multiple other projects though

Linking because I have the same (or maybe similar) issue. The differences could help solve your issue, and may help future readers.
